# How to set value of useState variable without passing reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have `users` and `selectedUser` as useState.

```
let users=[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}];

const [selectedUser, setselectedUser] = useState(undefined);

setselectedUser(users[0]);

var a = selectedUser;
a.firstName = "XYZ"
setselectedUser(a);
```

The above code changes the value of users to

```
[{"firstName":"XYZ", "lastName":"Doe"},
      {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
      {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}];
```

How can I prevent any changes to users when I change selectedUser?

Comment: Make a copy of the selected user using spread syntax: `var a = { ...selectedUser };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clone an object you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) `{...x}`.

```js
let users=[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}];

const newThing = {...users[0]}; // we clone the object
newThing.firstName = 'New name'

console.log(newThing, users);
// ^-- newThing has the new firstName but users remains untouched
```

So your example code would look like this:

```js
let users=[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
  {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
  {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}];

const [selectedUser, setselectedUser] = useState(undefined);

setselectedUser({...users[0]}); // <-- I changed this

var a = selectedUser;
a.firstName = "XYZ"
setselectedUser(a);
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you probably want to use an Object spread in this instance opposed to the array spread, otherwise this looks good

Comment: Yeah just fixed that ;)

Comment: This solution should work in this particular case, but extra caution is needed if the object to clone has nested objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dominik. @Mackers The solution doesn't work if the user object is nested. What's the correct way in this scenario?

Comment: Indeed @ArchitSandesara. That was not in your question ;) There are a bunch of solutions already out there to may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089058/nodejs-how-to-clone-an-object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710797/how-do-i-deep-clone-an-object-in-react