# Can't increase quantity in nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can’t increase the quantity in a nested array in any way, I have already tried many ways. I've tried spread, but it doesn't work. I need quantity to increase for a specific id. Please, instead of criticism, please write how to solve and what I'm doing wrong.
**I will be grateful for help.**  **Updated with suggestions**

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ClickId from "./ClickId";
import Cart from "./Cart";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: "Adidas"
        },
        {
          id: "Puma"
        },
        {
          id: "Nike"
        }
      ],
      countId: {
        quantityId: []
      }
    };
  }
  IncrementItem = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState)); // deep copy
      let products = this.state.products.map((p) => p.id);
      for (let i = 0; i < newState.countId.quantityId.length; i++) {
        if (newState.countId.quantityId[i].id === products) {
          newState.countId.quantityId[i].quantity += 1;
        }
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };
  DecrementItem = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState)); // deep copy
      for (let i = 0; i < newState.countId.quantityId.length; i++) {
        if (newState.countId.quantityId[i].id === this.state.products.id) {
          newState.countId.quantityId[i].quantity -= 1;
        }
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };
  CountId = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      countId: {
        ...this.state.countId,
        quantityId: this.state.countId.quantityId.concat({
          id: event.currentTarget.id,
          quantity: 1
        })
      }
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/ClickId"
              element={
                <ClickId CountId={this.CountId} countId={this.state.countId} />
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="/Cart"
              element={<Cart IncrementItem={this.IncrementItem} />}
            />
          </Routes>{" "}
        </BrowserRouter>{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**ClickId.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class ClickId extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: "Adidas"
        },
        {
          id: "Puma"
        },
        {
          id: "Nike"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  countId = () => {
    if (this.props.CountId) {
      this.props.CountId();
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((p) => {
          return (
            <div id={p.id} onClick={this.props.clickId}>
              ClickId
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Cart.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        {
          id: "Adidas"
        },
        {
          id: "Puma"
        },
        {
          id: "Nike"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((p) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.IncrementItem(p.id)}>
                +
              </button>
              <div className='s.count'>
                {JSON.stringify(
                  value.state.countId.quantityId.map((i) => i.quantity)
                )}
              </div>
              <button onClick={() => this.props.DecrementItem(p.id)}>
                -
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make the code syntactically correct

Comment: Pay attention that "products" are just strings and don't have `id`. So, `p.id` is always undefined here `this.state.products.find(p => p.id === i.id`

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov I'm sorry, I added an identifier to products, I didn't add it by mistake

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov I wrote under your answer

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov I'm trying to apply your solution but it doesn't work. The answer in quantity comes to me in the form of [1] and is not updated. Can you please write a working code and write an explanation for me to study it. I'll count the answer for you. products is all the products that are on the site, and countId.quantityId is information about the clicked product

Comment: I have no idea about data in `props`. Please provide more context. It would be perfect if you present it as `<App props={...}>`

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov In products.id I initially have products. The countId.quantityId contains data about the click in particular (id and quantity). I create a collection with this code:

CountId = (event) => {
    this.setState({
          countId:{
            ...this.state.countId,
            quantityId:
            this.state.countId.quantityId.concat({id:(event.currentTarget.id), quantity: 1})}})

I take the id of the product that is added to the cart and add quantity to it and this is how I create an object in countId.quantityId

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov Please check my changes. Code at that level of the test, taking into account your suggestions

Comment: thank you for extra details. I submitted an edit: formatted the code and added imports to make the code executable. Where did `value` come from in `Cart.js`?

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov Didn't understand you: "Where did value come from in Cart.js?" If you mean why I'm using Cart.js, it's the ultimate beneficiary of countId.quantityId.quantity

Comment: `value.state.countId.quantityId.map((i) => i.quantity)`. `value` is undefined in the `Cart`

Comment: I'm leaving the discussion. I don't have much time. Thank you for clarifications

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov value.state.countId.quantityId.map((i) => i.quantity). value is undefined in the Cart i am passing data through context instead of passing through props

Comment: @IvanReshetnikov Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: I researched a question with JSON and read an interesting answer to a question on stackoverflow and decided to use lodash for deep copying (I had a problem with deep copying) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710797/how-do-i-deep-clone-an-object-in-react

Answer (score 0):

You return `{ quantitiy: "{{updated value}}" }` from `setState`.

However, `setState`'s callback should return the same structure as `this.state` has (some fields of the first level can be omitted).

In your case it can look like

```js
this.setState(prevState => {
  var newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState)) // deep copy
  newState.countId.quantityId[0].quantity = "{{updated value}}"
  return newState
})
```

Example

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: [
        { id: 1, name: "Adidas", quantity: 1 },
        { id: 2, name: "Puma", quantity: 1 }
      ]
    };
  }
  IncrementItem = (id) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      var newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(prevState)); // deep copy
      for (let i = 0; i < newState.products.length; i++) {
        if (newState.products[i].id === id) {
          newState.products[i].quantity += 1;
        }
      }
      return newState;
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <button onClick={() => this.IncrementItem(product.id)}>
              {product.name} +
            </button>
          );
        })}
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with your answer. Could you explain in more detail. Thanks

Comment: @Nord, `newState` has the same structure with `this.state`. In your code the returned object has `quantity` key, which is absent in `this.state`

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long reply. I just got to see your reply. In your example, the error is in state. Products are the objects I get from Graphql and countId is the product click data.

Comment: @Nord, I've used another state on purpose. It's a working example with state updating. You can adapt it for your case. Key idea is that `setState` must return an object, which has properties/fields from `this.state`

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.