# Making a temp variable for a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Hell,

I have this line...

```
const tempStage = Object.assign({}, stage)
```

stage is an object type. Whenever I manipulate tempStage it affects stage.

Doing something like this for example changes the corresponding value in stage...

```
tempStage['$']['stageid']= "1234"
```

Can I get these two things to be independent of one another?

Comment: You could try cloning the object.  `const tempStage = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`, if there are no dates in the object.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS: Does Object.assign() create deep copy or shallow copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504682/js-does-object-assign-create-deep-copy-or-shallow-copy)

Comment: You need a deep copy for nested objects - e.g. lodash's `cloneDeep`