# Copying objects in js (need guidance on pass by reference from docs)

Tags: javascript, object, cloning, copying, mutability

I looked in the js docs and while studying the doc it mentioned in object.assign()
If the source value is a reference to an object, it only copies the reference value.

In my below snippet, one alters the original object and the other doesn't

```
    var objA = {
    a: 1,
    b: {
       c: 2,
       d: {
       e: 3,
     },
    },
  } 
var objC = { t: 1 };

  //why this works i.e adds a to objEmpty
// var objEmpty = Object.assign({}, { objC });  //this would add a prop to the objEmpty object

//this doesnt work i.e doesnt add a to objEmpty
var objEmpty = Object.assign({}, objC);  //this will not
objC.a = 3;

console.log(objC);

console.log(objEmpty);
```

I am getting my head around how really things work by trying different scenarios and I believe that it is something related to reference but how?

Another example from the docs

````
  const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { "a": 0, "b": { "c": 0}}

  obj1.a = 1;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1)); // { "a": 1, "b": { "c": 0}}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { "a": 0, "b": { "c": 0}}

  obj2.a = 2;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1)); // { "a": 1, "b": { "c": 0}}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { "a": 2, "b": { "c": 0}}
  obj2.b.c = 3;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1)); // { "a": 1, "b": { "c": 3}}
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj2)); // { "a": 2, "b": { "c": 3}}```

why does js behave this way? why the 3 got changed but the other didn't?

Thanks in advance :)
````

Comment: See [Does Object.assign() create deep copy or shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504682/js-does-object-assign-create-deep-copy-or-shallow-copy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does js behave this way? why the 3 got changed but the other
> didn't?

Because `Object.assign()` actually does **Shallow Copy**, you need to do **Deep Copy**

#### To do deep copy of an object.

There are bunch of ways, The most common and popular way is to use `JSON.stringify()` with `JSON.parse()`.

```js
const oldObj = {a: {b: 1}, c: 2};
const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj));
oldObj.a.b = 3; // will not affect the newObj
console.log('oldObj', oldObj);
console.log('newObj', newObj);
```

**Note:** There's a new JS standard called [`structured cloning`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone). It works on all browsers:

> method creates a **deep clone** of a given value using the structured clone algorithm.

```js
const clone = structuredClone(object);
```