Vue JS: How to prevent Input updating itself on livedata?
I'm passing data to Modal for editing. The problem is whenever my products data is updated (Every 5s via fetchData), input field in modal also changed. How to prevent it?
Below is a simplified version of my code.
<div id="app">
  <div class="modal" id="modal1">
    <form method="post">
      <input type="text" :value="passedData.category" />
      <input type="text" :value="passedData.rating" />
      <input type="text" :value="passedData.price" />
      <input type="text" :value="passedData.stock" />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <table>
    <tr v-for="item in items">
      <td>{{ item.sku }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.stock }}</td>
      <td><button @click="openModal('modal1', item)">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>

<script>
  const app = Vue.createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        passedData: [],
      };
    },
    mounted() {
      this.fetchData();
      setInterval(this.fetchData, 5000);
    },
    methods: {
      async fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products");
        const data = await response.json();
        this.items = data.products;
      },
      openModal(idModal, item) {
        this.passedData = Object.assign({}, item);
      },
    },
  });

  app.mount("#app");
</script>


The question lacks clear problem statement. Changed in which way? It's expected that it is reset to original state, this is something that the answer could fix

@EstusFlask No, it doesn't lacks anything. For JS programmers is his problem is absolutely clear.

@VladislavLadicky That the question is asked in a way you have to make assumptions proves otherwise. " input field in modal also changed" - can you say in which way? I can't. This is the asker's responsibility. Probably I'm not JS programmer enough

"input field in modal also changed" I mean it resets to original state. I want to prevent that. Sorry, english is not my native language.

As per this documentation - in your <input>'s, use v-model instead of :value - i.e.
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" v-model="passedData.category" />
        <input type="text" v-model="passedData.rating" />
        <input type="text" v-model="passedData.price" />
        <input type="text" v-model="passedData.stock" />
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>


That doesn't solve his problem/question.

@VladislavLadicky - are you sure about that? It actually WORKS, as opposed to your answer, which is basically  "do what you currently do, but use a library to do it"

Using v-model makes the input not reset, which is the result I'm looking for. But using v-model also changed value from the table. By using v-model.lazy I can delay those changes. But is there any proper way to keep table's value unchanged?

using v-model also changed value from the table no, it doesn't

It does. v-model is a two-way binding right? what typed on input is reflected back to the parent. Since my interval is 5000ms it was only shown briefly, but I have other pages that have longer refresh interval.

you must be doing something wrong then - I tested on play.vuejs.org and the input field remained as entered, and the table remained unchanged - did you want what is entered in the inputs to be reflected in the table? because that is not what your question is about

did you want what is entered in the inputs to be reflected in the table? no, this is what I want to prevent.

then go with v-model, and, if the rest of your code is identical to what you posted, you should be good to go

okay I tried it on JS playground and it indeed working as expected. I must be doing something wrong on my real code. Thanks for your help.

In the "openModal" method, when you open the modal window, you have to make an independent clone of the passedData variable.
Which is also poorly defined - you claim it's an Array, but in the form you access it as an object.
And be careful: creating an independent clone can be a challenge. Better get "npm i lodash" and import cloneDeep in this component via import cloneDeep from "lodash/cloneDeep".

It's reassigned with plain object with this.passedData = Object.assign({}, item). Which also makes it a clone

Well, that's exactly the mistake. @EstusFlask

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504682/does-object-assign-create-a-deep-copy-or-a-shallow-copy

What exactly? That passedData is initially an array is a mistake, but this doesn't affect how the reactivity works. And it's assigned with plain object later that clones "item" data. It seems to contain only string values, this can be seen from its usage, so a clone is as deep as it's necessary. From what I see, another answer addresses more practical problem in original code, still a feedback from the OP is required in order for the answers to not speculate

Have you tried your solution?

"You have to make an independent clone of the passedData variable"
how to do this? this is not a full Vue JS package, will lodash work without npm?

since the original data is JSON - JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)) is one way - though, since the properties you are using are all top level, your Object.assign is perfectly OK
